# Activity A that starts B that starts C. Why pressing the back button in C goes back to A?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm quite a newbie with Android programming.

I have a MainActivity from which I start a SecondActivity:

```
[...]
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mode", eTravelEditMode.Create);
startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_CREATE);
[...]

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MainActivity.REQUEST_CREATE) {
    }
}
```

In the SecondActivity, I start a ThirdActivity:

```
[...]
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SecondActivity.REQUEST_SELECT);
[...]

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //this method is never called
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SecondActivity.REQUEST_SELECT) {
        [...]
    }
```

In the ThirdActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //intent.putExtra("returnValue", (Serializable) mAdapter.getSelectedValues());
    setResult(SecondActivity.RETURN_SELECT, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

From ThirdActivity I would like to return a value to its parent SecondActivity when I press the back button.
But then, the SecondActivity.onActivityResult is never called. 
The MainActivity.onActivityResult is called.

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: Are you maybe calling `finish()` anywhere in your SecondActivity..?

Comment: Second activity is getting destroyed somewhere.

Comment: @vucko: there is no finish() call in 2nd activity

Answer (score 2):

Yeah handling intents and managing the activity stack can be tricky no matter how experienced you are at developing for android.  Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to press the back button in order to move forward in your app logic.  There are 3 points I have:

1. *Explaination*: If you want to move back to SecondActivity from ThirdActivity, just
   calling `finish()` will do that for you, since you started the third
   activity using startActivityForResult(intent) vs using
   startActivity(intent).  So whats happening in your code I think, is
   that you're actually going back through android's Back Stack
   navigation system, **and** going back again through `finish()`.  So your going back twice pretty much, which is why you're ending up back at main activity.  I think.

   More info about the activity stack and back navigation can be found
   here:
   https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html
2. *Suggestion*: Try adding a button and in the onClick() method for that button have
   your `finish()`, instead of using the android back navigation.  I would stay away from using you back button as a
   means of progression for your app.
3. *Suggestion*: If logically the user would be going from ActivityTwo to
   ActivityThree and back to ActivityTwo, I would either have the
   `finish()` be a natural progression in your app logic, since
   generally that's what you want for startActivityForResult(intent) vs
   startActivity(intent).

Comment: I think yours is the best answer so far. However, calling `finish()` is not a very healthy choice. The article describes Activity hierarchy. The proper way to do this is to declare parent Activities

Comment: True, but my interpretation was that kevinob wanted to start the third activity with just for the purposes of producing some result, so he really shouldn't be using the back button at all and just using `finish()`.  And I though that if you start an activity using `startActivityForResult()`, using `finish()` was the proper way of ending that activity's lifecycle, no?

Comment: `finish()` is a very healthy choice. More than that, in this case it's the correct choice. Parent activities are used for something different, for "up navigation".

Comment: I tried with finish() only (removed the super.onBackPressed call), tried calling the finish from a button. It always lands in the MainActivity...damn.

Comment: hmm interesting, just wondering how do you know that it just skips back to main activity?  Are you putting a breakpoint in SecondActivity's onActivityResult and its not hitting it or are you like logging something in onActivityResult?  Sorry I'm not doubting what your telling is true, I just want to know some more info about the issue.

Comment: Also, I just read your comment to vucko above, if you're not calling `finish()` in SecondActivity, why are you starting SecondActivity with `startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_CODE)` instead of `startActivity(intent)`? You only want to be using startActivityForResult if you intend to only use the activity your about to start to produce some result and get that result back to the original activity.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".forms.SecondActivity"
          android:label="@string/mylabel"
          android:noHistory="true"
>
```

I removed "android:noHistory="true"" and now everything works smoothly.
A copy/paste from an helloworld I think, I'm confused! :)
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Try This!

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, A.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You are just stacking Activities on top of each other. This is not a complete solution.